# Doc2vec Gensim: the word embeddings not updating during each epoch

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I use Gensim Doc2vec model to train document vectors.
I printed out representations for the word 'good', but I found every epoch, I found not updating! While I printed out representations for the document with id '3', every epoch different!

My codes are below, do not know what is happening.

```
model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(dm = 0, alpha=0.1, size= 20, min_alpha=0.025)

model.build_vocab(documents)

print ('Building model....',(time4-time3))
for epoch in range(10):
    model.train(documents)

    print('Now training epoch %s' % epoch)
    print(model['good'])
    print(model.docvecs[str(3)])
```

Answer (score 3):

The pure PV-DBOW model (`dm=0`) doesn't involve use or training of word-vectors at all. (It's just an artifact of the shared-code with `Word2Vec` that they're allocated and randomly-initialized at all.)

If you want word-vectors to be trained in an interleaved fashion, you must use the non-default `dbow_words=1` parameter. (Or, switch to PV-DM mode, `dm=1`, where word-vectors are inherently involved.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to check representations after every update.
Gensim `doc2vec` uses an `iter` parameter to define what the number of epochs should be (see [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)), whose `default` value is 5.

Essentially what is happening in the following loop:

```
for epoch in range(10):
    model.train(documents)
```

you are training your model **10 times, from scratch to 5 epochs**.

I don't think Gensim at present allows, to check representations after every epoch. One **crude** way of doing it would be:

```
model.train(documents, iter=1)
print('Now training epoch %s' % epoch)
print(model['good'])
print(model.docvecs[str(3)])

model.train(documents, iter=2)
print('Now training epoch %s' % epoch)
print(model['good'])
print(model.docvecs[str(3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

in every epoch gensim use random value for word vector at first and then start to train model. in doc2vec(or word2vec) shouldn't every final word vector for a word(exp. 'good') are same but the similar word are similar word vectors. for example in one epoch:

```
model['good'] = [0.22 0.52 0.36]
model['better'] = [0.24 0.50 0.39]
```

and in another epoch:

```
model['good'] = [0.58 0.96 0.24]
model['better'] = [0.59 0.90 0.21]
```

Comment: I didn't get what you are implying. (1) In every epoch, word vectors don't start at random, but from the previous value of the word vector. Only in the first epoch, word vectors start from random.

Comment: every time you call "train" function , word vector get the random value for word vectors. in other word "train" function start training model from the begining and word vector get random value.

Comment: That's correct. `train` function starts training model from beginning. Since default value of `seed` parameter of the `train` function is fixed to be 0, every time you start training, word vectors would be initialized to same random values, and after `n epochs`, you will get same vectors (essentially experiments are reproducible)

Comment: The word-vectors are only randomly initialized during `build_vocab()` – specifically `finalize_vocab()` and `reset_weights()`. Further calls to `train()` don't reset or re-initialize the vectors. (While you *can* call `train()` multiple times, it's usually a mistake – better to just use `iter` and let the class handle multiple passes and proper alpha-decay itself.)